# Woocommerce shop_manager role

Tags: woocommerce

after some trial and error I have managed to edit some of my shop_manager roles. See below.
However, when I remove_cap( 'manage_woocommerce'); it removes the menu, but then it adds 2 new menus for 'orders' and 'discount voucher'. I seem unable to remove these 2 items as they are new in the menu, but I cannot find the relevant property. Does anybody know how to remove these?

(all I want is the shop manager to add and edit products, nothing else)

```
$result = add_role(
'shop_manager',
        __( 'Shop Manager' ),
array(

$role = get_role( 'shop_manager' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_published_posts' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_published_pages' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'delete_published_pages' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'delete_published_posts' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_theme_options' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'view_woocommerce_reports' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'moderate_comments' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'manage_woocommerce' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'manage_woocommerce_orders' ), // does not seem to work
$role->remove_cap( 'manage_woocommerce_coupons' ), //does not seem to work
)
);
```

I already looked at the following sources but cannot figure it out:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/250fcc96a3ea4b1150eb3e94fa45e968ce4340aa/includes/class-wc-install.php#L942

Answer (score 0):

You can change role and capabilities of each user, see an example below for shop_manager.
Please note that when you run this in functions.php these will be stored in your database. In order to change it back you need to add/remove. Simply removing the code won't undo this as it's stored in the database.

```
$result = add_role(
'shop_manager',
    __( 'Shop Manager' ),
array(

$role = get_role( 'shop_manager' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_published_posts' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_published_pages' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'delete_published_pages' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'delete_published_posts' ),
$role->add_cap( 'edit_posts' ),
$role->add_cap( 'edit_pages' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_woocommerce_coupons' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'edit_shop_coupons' ),
$role->remove_cap( 'export' ),
)
);
```